# How to install Ethernet LAN in windows Xp?

Tags: windows-xp, lan

I am having windows xp System.I want to install LAN to access the internet connection.I have got the broadband connection.Is there any driver to be installed for using LAN.If so Please tell me the site where i can get the software downloaded.Please help me out.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warrior,

You would need the drivers for the Ethernet port on your computer. These are usually installed by default though.
One way to check is to go into Device Manager and check if the Device is installed correctly, i.e does not have a yellow triangle next to it.
If this is correct you need to connect your pc to your router / firewall, you haven't specified your equipment so i'm hypothesising, and check that your pc is getting an IP address from your router or if you have set it statically that it is in the correct range.
If all this is correct then you should be able to ping your router.
Assuming that your DNS settings are correct, normally you would get them from your router / firewall by default, then you should be able to get the internet.
If you still can't I would call up your ISP and enquire why you cannot.

Comment: How can i install the device properly?

Comment: Is the device showing as Not installed in Device Manager?
Is the ethernet port on a seperate card or is it included as part of the motherboard?
If it is on a seperate Card you will need the device Drivers for that Card. If it is on the motherboard then you should have the CD that comes with the Motherboard, this will contain the drivers for your Ethernet Port. If not you will have to find the drivers on the internet,

What Kind of system is it?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, your question is not that clear -

If your machine already has a ethernet socket, simply plug a cable in to it then the other end in to the router and it should be able to pick up all the settings via DHCP.

If you do not currently have an ethernet socket, you can buy a card quite cheap. Most of the off the shelf ones will be supported out the box in Windows XP. They will usually also have drivers included on a cd, or you can get updated ones from the chipset manufacturers site (e.g. [Intel](http://www.intel.com), [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw) e.t.c.).

Hope this helps, if it doesn't, please say in comments what the problem is.

Comment: It already has Ethernet socket.How to install it properly?